# What am I doing wrong when I try to set a switch voltage on LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice

I was trying to set a switch voltage, I follow in according every tutorial that I've saw on the internet. However, I'm getting the warning saying : "Cant find the the model of SW." But it doesn't make sense, the  voltage switches are in the project and I've put in the spice directive exactly as in the tutorias

[image: switches image and spice directives]
[image: warning image]

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the "Value" field to ST1, ST2, etc in the switch instance.  You are only changing the name.

[image: sw-spice]

Comment: Would it be possible to rephrase this to be "rename the 'Value' field instead of the instance name ('InstName') in the attribute editor" (or similar, but same keywords)? My native language is not English, but it might be perceived more clearly by future readers.

Comment: thanks, it worked.